# How do I insert the Context type from GraphQL into a Rust test?

Tags: rust, graphql, async-graphql

Anyone worked with the async graphql crate here?

I have a `create_book` function as part of my MutationResolver that receives the graphql async `Context` type in order to pull out the Datastore struct.

```
use async_graphql::{Context, Object, Result, ID};

async fn create_book(
    &self,
    ctx: &Context<'_>,
    table: String,
    name: String,
    author: String,
) -> Result<Book> {
    let data_store = ctx.data_unchecked::<Datastore>();
    let res = create_book(data_store, table, name, author).await.unwrap();
    Ok(res)
}

//Test

//ERROR MESSAGE with Context below: expected value, found type alias `Context`
//can't use a type alias as a constructor

 #[tokio::test]
async fn test_01_try_create_book() {
    let table = "users".to_string();
    let name = "HP".to_string();
    let author = "JKR".to_string();

    let test = MutationResolver
        .create_book(&Context, table, name, author)
        .await
        .unwrap();
}
```

How come my test is complaining that it can't take Context as a param but no corresponding issues with the create_book function taking the Context type?

Comment: He seems to have found this:
https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-do-i-pass-the-context-type-from-the-async-graphql-crate-into-a-test/91500/3